# How to add multiple jQuery populated HTML numbers together from different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a first time poster and I'm learning jQuery, so I'll try to formulate my words as best as possible.

On my site I have multiple pages that dynamically add up the lis and gives me a number.
That number is displayed this way: `var totalOverallString = $("#overallTotal").html(total);`
Currently I have two similar variables in two functions.
Everything is working correctly on the individual pages.
Now I want to take those two numbers, add them, and display that new number in my home page.

I want this to work dynamically like in my other pages.
The problem I run into is getting those numbers from the other pages.

I've tried `.load` and `.getScript` to extract the numbers.  I've also tried doing a callback function, but the script loads and gives me the original declared variable: `total = 0`.  This makes sense to me.  It's not adding up the lis from the original page. Both variables are global.

I'm trying my best to wrap my head around how to do this.  How do I get that dynamically added `.html(total)` from the other page?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The numbers your JS is adding up - are they stored in a database or just static in the HTML?

Comment: Good question.  The numbers are just the result of adding all the lis on a particular page.  Then the HTML in the ID is altered with that number.  So I want to say static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I can think to do it without storing all the list items in a database or similar.

Example page 1 containing some list items, here called `list-1.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Example page 2 containing some list items, here called `list-2.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Example page where you want the count of list items to be displayed, in this case, your homepage:

```
<html>
<body>

    <!-- Element to contain the total -->
    <p>Total list items: <span id="count">counting...</span></p>

    <!-- Include jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        (function() {
            // Update this array of URLs to the pages containing <li>s that you want to count. 
            var urls = ["list-one.html", "list-two.html"];

            var $hidden = $("<ul />").hide();
            var total = 0;

            // use jQuery's selective loading functionality to load LIs from each URL, count them, and add the count to a running total
            for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                $hidden.load(urls[i] + " li", function(responseText) {
                    total = total + $hidden.find("li").length;

                    // complete - update the count element.
                    if(i == urls.length) {
                        $("#count").html(total);
                    }
                });
            }
       })();

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So essentially we are requesting each page containing list items to count, counting all list items on those pages and keeping a running total.

N.B. depending on the number of pages and lists you need to count, this may **not** be particularly efficient. But it will work, and I think is the only realistic way you can achieve this without using a DB or complex scraping/caching systems.

Comment: I had a similar idea but I was worried about the efficiency.  All the answers so far have been very helpful!  I think I'm going to accept this answer.  Thanks to Java Seeker for his input as well.  I tried the localStorage, but like everyone is saying, I would need access to a database.

Comment: Yup, a database would be the efficient way of doing this. But if you only have a handful of pages and list items, there's no need to go overboard with efficiency. Will it be possible to see where this is in use, out of interest?

Comment: Absolutely!  My site is under some maintenance, so things might be out of place.  Currently I don't pay for server space, and I just use Weebly to host my site.  So the http://www.royoswalt44.com/base-inserts-parallels.html has 882, and http://www.royoswalt44.com/autographs.html has 180.  I haven't designated a space on the home page, but somewhere 1062 would be displayed.  As you can see, the lis contain images, links, text, etc.  So I would have to hide quite a few things.  I just got into jQuery, so I have been fiddling around with the functionality of my lists.

Comment: Cool beans. Yeah I don't know how well it will perform with that number of items..! You'll have to try it and see. Did you consider the obvious alternative of manually updating a total..? Not as fun though ;)

Comment: Ha yes of course I did, but where's the fun in that! :)  Currently, my individual totals update with ease just by adding a new li to any page.  So to have my entire site working in sync would have been very cool.  Not a big deal.  I'm pretty happy with how far my site has come along in the last month or so.  I'll give your code a whirl later today.  I do have a question: what other elements would I have to hide?  Would that load the entire site into $hidden?  Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be working, and the amount of code is acceptable.  I only need to count up amounts from five pages.  Thanks again for making my first question here an enjoyable experience.

Comment: Pleasure! As for hiding other elements, there's no need – the `var $hidden = $("<ul />").hide();` line creates a new hidden UL element to use with jQuery's .load(), which requires an element to load content into, in order to use the page fragment loading feature. See 'Loading Page Fragments' on http://api.jquery.com/load/ for info :) Good luck with your collecting!

Comment: Ok I've worked in your code and stylized it for my site.  It's working like a charm.  I'll continue to fiddle around with certain things, but this is how it looks right now: http://www.royoswalt44.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can store your individual values into localStorage or sessionStorage which availlbe with HTML5

There are two new objects for storing data on the client:

```
localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
sessionStorage - stores data for one session
```

you can use localStorage or sessionStorage is client side cookies  to store your individual value, then you are going to show your total into different page retrieve the value from localStorage and show it :)

Again if you dont want to cache total values set expire time of localStorage 0 which will be expired when browser closed.

for more details on localStorage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Would this be the best overall strategy?  I don't know that much about cookies yet (I'll read up on it now).  I want that number to be updated every time I add or subtract a new li.

Comment: one thing, do you want to show the last total values when you close browser and open again?

Comment: Yea I want it to be permanent HTML.  Then when I add an li to any of my other pages, my home page is automatically updated.  This strategy is working on any individual page, but I want to find a way for the other pages to interact with the home page.  I'm thinking localStorage might be the way to go.  I'll work on it now.

Comment: one problem with localStorage, this is client side storage so this update will not be visilbe to other users.if user change browser it will not be visible to other user.

Comment: for permanent and make visible to all user you have to store those data into database and when you reload your page where you are showing total count number grab the total value from database.

Comment: Yea it's becoming clear that I would need to retrieve them from a database.